# source, destination, distance - calculate the source and destination with longest distance

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures

I am trying to solve a problem that calculates the greatest distance between any two points.

I am expecting the output to calculate the source and destination pair that has the highest distance traveled.

```
      obj = [{
                source: a,
                destination: b,
                distance: 200
              },
              {
                source: b,
                destination: a,
                distance: 100
              },
              {
                source: a,
                destination: c,
                distance: 100
              }
            ]
```

In this case, my output would be highestDistance = [a, b, 300] ( between a and b => 200 + 100 = 300)

I am trying to write a function in javascript. what data structure would be appropriate here?

I have initially tried creating a map and adding the [source, destination] tuple as a key like so:

```
 {
   [a, b]: 200,
   [a, c]: 100
 }

const obj = [{
                source: a,
                destination: b,
                distance: 200
              },
              {
                source: b,
                destination: a,
                distance: 100
              },
              {
                source: a,
                destination: c,
                distance: 100
              }
            ]

    function highestDistance(obj) {
          const highestPair = obj[0];
          const myMap = new Map();
          obj.forEach(pair => {
            let [source, destination] = [pair.source, pair.destination];
            if( myMap.has([source, destination]) || myMap.has([source, destination])){
                myMap.set() 
                 // not sure how to proceed and add the tuple to map here
                // I intend to compare the current highest and update highestPair value if the current pair distance is collectively bigger.
            } else {
              myMap.set([source, destination], pair[distance])
           }

          })

          return obj;
        }
```

Input:

```
      {
        source: a,
        destination: b,
        distance: 200
      },
      {
        source: b,
        destination: a,
        distance: 100
      },
      {
        source: a,
        destination: c,
        distance: 100
      }
```

Output:

```
[a, b, 300]
```

Can you please help me in solving this? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create an object with distances. later you need to find max distance.

```
var obj = [{
                source: 'a',
                destination: 'b',
                distance: 200
              },
              {
                source: 'b',
                destination: 'a',
                distance: 100
              },
              {
                source: 'a',
                destination: 'c',
                distance: 100
              }
            ]

var distMap = obj.reduce((f, n)=> {
  const {source,destination, distance } = n;
  const key  = `${source}->${destination}`
  const key2 = `${destination}->${source}`

  if(f[key2]){
    f[key2] = distance+ f[key2]
  } else {
    f[`${source}->${destination}`] = distance
  }
  return f
}, {}) // {a->b: 300, a->c: 100}
```